# How to mirror my iPhone 6s on and iPad Pro

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have developed an iPhone app and would like to present it to a small group of people using the larger screen on my iPad Pro.  The app does not run on iPad, so I would like to mirror my iPhone screen on the iPad.

Can this be done?  If not, any suggestions.

Comment: When you say it 'does not run on the iPad', what do you mean?  I have several iPhone apps (that don't have iPad apps) that I run on my iPad Pro without a problem.

Comment: I developed my iPhone app and intentionally designed it so I would only support iPhone.  It takes additional work to support iPad because of the different form factor, etc.

Comment: I've developed several iPhone-only apps and they run fine on an iPad.  Granted, unless you specify an iPad-specific storyboard (or code) it will only display the iPhone view on the iPad.  Have you tried to run it on an iPad?  I ask because unless you specifically coded it to not run on an iPad, it should still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a way to do this without an intermediary device. If you have a Mac, you can connect your iPhone to your computer via Lightning cable and open QuickTime Player and select File > New Movie Recording. When the window opens, press the carat/arrow next to the record button to select your iPhone. You can fullscreen this window and it mirrors your iPhone's screen.

If you really need to have it on your iPad, you could do a VNC screen share the above from your Mac to your iPad.

Comment: drivec, what is a VNC screen? Thanks.

Comment: VNC (virtual network computing) screen sharing is a one method for sharing screens. If you have a Mac, you can follow the directions for setting up the Mac here: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25554?locale=en_US - You will still need to use a screen sharing client on your iPad. I personally use this one: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vnc-viewer/id352019548?mt=8

Comment: I do have a mac and this looks like an approach that will work for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that the iPad contains a (1X/2X) emulator for all iPhone apps (except those that specifically require telephony).  So just run the iPhone app on your iPad.  No iPad code, storyboards, or iPad specific or Universal settings in Xcode are required to do this.